# How to increase list View's Separator length in Xamarin forms iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to increase list View's Separator length(spacing between two cells).

I am  not getting how can I do it in xamarin forms by using custom renderer and I am looking for iOS only.

I want to create card view in iOS (by using xamarin forms) just like facebook application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Implemented it with frame control.

1.I created one customized cell in List View (Using ViewCell).
Then Added frame in it.

2.Removed Separator in a List View by Using Custom Renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Use HasUnevenRows="True" in your ListView and it should adapt to your item height.